# Windows 8 metro UI: what is a new place for tray notification icons?

Tags: windows-8

Before windows 8, if application want to non-intrusively inform user that something happens, it displays tray icon, maybe animated. For example, if e-mail application finds a new e-mail, it displays a new tray icon (outlook) or animate it's own icon in tray (all other e-mail clients).

With new Windows 8 Metro UI it's a new screen with tiles that supposed to be a main thing user will use to launch and switch apps. Where is no tray area in this mode, but many other things - charms area, something like status area that displays clock and battery usage etc.

According to Microsoft Metro UI design guides - what is the new place for poor e-mail app notification icon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you want is a [notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779722.aspx).  There are three kinds of notifications: a tile update, a badge update on the tile or a ["toast"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465448.aspx) in the upper right corner of the screen (when in another application).  The various options for these types of notifications are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779721.aspx#notification_delivery_methods).

Comment: +1.  Much more specific (and helpful, since you linked right to the documentation) than my answer.  Good links!

Comment: @Eyeofhell Is there some way I could improve this answer?

Answer (score 1):

The new place to let someone know your app has updated information is the tile itself.

These are called "Live Tiles" because they're intended to be dynamic, and change as new data becomes available.

http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-feature-focus-tiles-143175